# Groupby fazendo consulta ficar muito lenta

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

Boa tarde galera, estou fazendo uma consulta no banco onde tudo ocorre bem, no entanto quando eu faço o uso do "groupby" essa consulta fica muito lenta, muito lenta mesmo, exemplo, basta tirar a linha do groupby que a consulta me retorna em menos de 1 segundo, com a linha do groupby a consulta demora cerca de 25 segundos ou mais. :/

Código da consulta:

```
$query = DB::table('recmovto')
                ->join('receita', 'recmovto.receitaId', '=', 'receita.id')
                ->join('natureza_receita', 'receita.naturezaId', '=', 'natureza_receita.id')
                ->select('natureza_receita.natureza as a', 'natureza_receita.nome as b',
                        DB::raw("(Select valorAno from fonte_receita where receitaId = receita.id) as  c"),
                        DB::raw("(Select sum(valor) from recmovto where substr(data, 6, 2) = ".$request->valorMensal." and receitaId = receita.id) as d"),
                        DB::raw("(Select sum(valor) from recmovto where receitaId = receita.id and substr(data, 6, 2) between 01 and ".$request->valorMensal.") as e"))
                ->groupby('recmovto.receitaId')
                ->orderby('recmovto.data', 'desc');
```